# Mailgun domain not found: example.com

Tags: digital-ocean, mailgun

I am trying to setup emails with my own website. Let's say the domain name is `example.com`.

The name server in use is digital ocean and I also have a gmail account linked to the same (say using `contact@example.com`).

While setting up things with mailgun, I used `mg.example.com` (as they said it would also let me email using the root domain). The verification step is done and I can send email using `contact@mg.example.com`.

However, trying to use the root domain (`contact@example.com`) gives the following error:

```
AnymailRequestsAPIError: Sending a message to me@gmail.com from contact@example.com
ESP API response 404:
{
"message": "Domain not found: example.com"
}
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 8/22/16:**
Anymail has been updated to take a new MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN in `settings.py`. See version .5+ docs.

--
**Original Answer**
You did not post your code for how you're sending your email, but you are probably trying to send using the simple send_mail() function:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail("Subject", "text body", "contact@abc.example",
          ["to@example.com"],)
```

When you use this method, Anymail pulls the domain out of your From address and tries to use this with Mailgun. Since your From address (`abc.example`) doesn't include the subdomain mg., Mailgun is confused.

Instead, you need to send the email using the `EmailMultiAlternatives` object and specify the Email Sender Domain like so:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives("Subject", "text body",
                             "contact@abc.example", ["to@example.com"])
msg.esp_extra = {"sender_domain": "mg.abc.example"}

msg.send()
```

Don't forget the brackets in your To field, as this needs to be a tuple or list even if you're only sending it to one recipient.

For more information, see Anymail docs on [esp_extra](https://anymail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esps/mailgun/).

Comment: Please note, a new setting is being added to AnyMail that makes this more straight-forward. See comments in [this issue](https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail/issues/26#issuecomment-237367993).

Answer (score 83):

I got the same error when I copy-pasted the `curl` example from Mailgun help page.

My domain was set to EU region, and I had to set the api domain to `api.eu.mailgun.net` instead of `api.mailgun.net`.

Boom! Working! :)

Comment: Thanks! The curl example of their docs also includes multiple `to` fields.

Comment: Well, to me it seemed to be this, but now the tutorial shows `mxa.eu.mailgun.org` and `mxb.eu.mailgun.org.` instead of `api.mailgun.net`, and I wonder, what is now the right behavior, are your api domain outdated ?

Answer (score 48):

I am using the EU region with Mailgun and have run into this problem myself. My implementation is a `Node.js` application with the `mailgun-js` [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js).

**EU Region Implementation:**

```js
const mailgun = require("mailgun-js");
const API_KEY = "MY_API_KEY";   // Add your API key here
const DOMAIN = "my-domain.example"; // Add your domain here
const mg = mailgun({
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    domain: DOMAIN,
    host: "api.eu.mailgun.net"  // -> Add this line for EU region domains
});
const data = {
    from: "Support <support@my-domain.example>",
    to: "recipient@example.com",
    subject: "Hello",
    text: "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"
};
mg.messages().send(data, function(error, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(body);
    }
});
```

Further `options` for the `mailgun()` constructor can be [found here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js#options).

Thought I'd share a full answer for anybody that's still confused. Additionally, Mailgun Support was kind enough to supply the following table as a reference guide:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I was pulling out my hair trying to figure out why this is not working. Adding the `host` property fixed it for me.

Comment: Absolute legend, took about an hour to find this but solved all hy issues in a single line of code (the fact that EU domains need the host property in the config is not obvious!)

Comment: Thanks! Same experience here: didn't realise the `host` property defaults to the US domain, so I was getting "domain not found' until I added it with along with the EU mailgun host.

Comment: Finally: the **host** key!! - Thanks!  It's always a great idea to read the package documentation. It would have saved me hours!

Answer (score 8):

`IF`:

- your domain is an EU domain AND
- you're using `django-anymail` as in Rob's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38058296/1211429) above

`THEN` the `ANYMAIL` setting (in your Django project settings) should specify the `API_URL` to be the EU one, example:

```
ANYMAIL = {
    'MAILGUN_API_KEY': '<MAILGUN_API_KEY>',
    'MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN': 'example.eu',
    'MAILGUN_API_URL': 'https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3'  # this line saved me!
}
```

Before adding the `MAILGUN_API_URL` I was getting this error:

```
AnymailRequestsAPIError: Sending a message to xxx@example.com from noreply@example.eu <noreply@example.eu>
Mailgun API response 404 (NOT FOUND):
{
  "message": "Domain not found: mailgun.example.eu"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Struggled for days with correct DNS settings and finally found as @wiktor said, i needed to add "eu" to api endpoint to make it work. Its actually also documented here: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-intro.html#mailgun-regions

Sorry for replying as an answer, dont have enough rep to add comment :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: 404 error, domain not found.

**The cause**
The EU region selection for the domain on Mailgun

**The solution**
Change the region from EU back to the default of US.

Since I had not used the domain at all up to this point, I simply deleted it, re-added it, then changed my TXT, MX and CNAME records (for example, mailgun.org instead of eu.mailgun.org) at the domain registrar (which was GoDaddy in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I found my fix with this change:

```py
ANYMAIL = {
   ...
   'MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN': 'example.com', # Using the sending domain in Mailgun
}
```